# How prevent from hacking personal computer and using my jaxx account

Tags: security, e-wallet

It looks like anyone who can hack a computer has direct access to the jaxx wallet stored on the hard drive.  Is there any way to block access like requiring a strong password to open the wallet? 
Thanks, jat

Comment: I just answered a similiar question here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53392/protection-against-malware-attacks. On JAXX wallet I'd ask some other specialist to reply. Hint: a strong password protection does not help too much, cause latest security issue showed, that malware not only accesses the data, it installs as well keyloggers (in the sound driver of all HP systems). So another strong password only increases a bit the level of security. Two factor would be the way to go.